# why does list[x] go to the next element in python every time?

Tags: python, list, operating-system, element

I am trying to create a code that will do SSTF scheduling and I am doing well figuring out how to initiate the code. my teacher have put up other disk scheduling code examples to help us out and he uses this code to move through the list of numbers properly for a first come first serve disk scheduling algorithm, in order to do the math and get the right number of movements. I know what it's doing I just don't know how, is `requests[x]` able to go to the next number every time? cause to me I feel like it would just go to random numbers or the number thats always at the front(so if its [0,1,2,3] it will always show 0). Here's his code:

```
for x in range(len(requests)):
        movement += abs(position - requests[x])
        position = requests[x]
        print ("Servicing " + str(position))
```

So as I said I know exactly what the code is saying and doing I just don't understand how does the [x] part will always know to go to the next number.
if you need the list of `requests :   requests = [2069, 1212, 2296, 2800, 544, 1618, 356, 1523, 4965, 3681]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is in a loop:

```
for x in range(len(requests)):
    movement += abs(position - requests[x])
    position = requests[x]
    print("Servicing " + str(position))
```

In the `for x in range` line, we declare the loop as going through each value in `range(len(requests))`.

`len(requests)` is the length of the `requests` array - the number of elements in it. So for `requests = [2069, 1212, 2296]`, `len(requests)` would be 3.

`range()` gives an array of all integers from zero up to, but not including, the argument. So `range(len(requests))` is `range(3)` which gives `[0, 1, 2]`. We are looping over each of those values.

The first time the code in the loop is run, `x = 0`. This means `position = requests[0]`, the first element in the `requests` array.

The second time, `x = 1`. This means `position` is set to `requests[1]`, the second element. The third time, `x = 2`, the third element, and so on.

`x` is simply taking on a different value for each iteration of the loop - which gives the behavior you ask about.